# Swift fit annotations

Tags: swift, parse-platform, annotations, location

I have a few locations in parse which I'm query-ing. It shows all annotations but it only zoom the last one. How can I find max and min latitudes and longitudes and make them fit ?

There is plenty of these on stackoverflow but they're almost all in objective-c.

[image]

Comment: Please, do not post screenshots of code.  Instead, copy and paste the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples in Objective-C are still essentially valid since the underlying SDK/API is still the same -- just being called using a different language (and there's always the documentation).

To show all annotations, there are essentially two ways to do it:

1. Use the convenient `showAnnotations` method.  You pass it an array of annotations and it will automatically calculate a reasonable region to display.  You call it after adding all the annotations (after your `for` loop).  In fact, `showAnnotations` will even add the annotations itself if they aren't already on the map.  To show all annotations that are already on the map, just pass it the map's own `annotations` array.  Example:

   ```
   self.mapView.showAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations, animated: true)
   ```
2. If you are not happy with the default region calculated by `showAnnotations`, you can calculate one yourself.  Instead of calculating minimum/maximum latitudes and longitudes, etc, I prefer to use the built-in `MKMapRectUnion` function to create an `MKMapRect` that fits all annotations and then call `setVisibleMapRect(mapRect,edgePadding,animated)` which lets one conveniently define padding in screen points around the fitted map rect.    This technique was originally found in a very early map view sample app from Apple.  Example:

   ```
   var allAnnMapRect = MKMapRectNull

   for object in objects! {
       //existing code that creates annotation...
       //existing code that calls addAnnotation...

       let thisAnnMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate)
       let thisAnnMapRect = MKMapRectMake(thisAnnMapPoint.x, thisAnnMapPoint.y, 1, 1)
       allAnnMapRect = MKMapRectUnion(allAnnMapRect, thisAnnMapRect)
   }

   //Set inset (blank space around all annotations) as needed...
   //These numbers are in screen CGPoints...
   let edgeInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)

   self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(allAnnMapRect, edgePadding: edgeInset, animated: true)
   ```

Comment: Thank you Anna, this works like a charm :) I'm not good at objective-c, so it's pretty confusing sometimes, and I'm just learning swift for 15 days