# Zoom MKMapView to fit polyline points in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, mkmapview, mkpolyline

I've been looking for a solution to zooming a MapView in to fit the boundaries of an MKPolyline in Swift. I have been able to locate example code for Objective-C [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569327/zoom-mkmapview-to-fit-polyline-points), but I'm not at all familiar with Objective-C or how to convert it into Swift.

Would anyone have an example of this in Swift? Thanks.

```
-(void)zoomToPolyLine: (MKMapView*)map polyline: (MKPolyline*)polyline animated: (BOOL)animated
{
[map setVisibleMapRect:[polyline boundingMapRect] edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0) animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: See the last two lines of code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317517/swift-fit-annotations) (don't need the looping or anything -- just the `let edgeInset = ...` onwards).  Replace allAnnMapRect with polyline.boundingMapRect.

Comment: Anna, that's worked a treat. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13):

This code sets the region to display the entire polyline, along with 12.5% padding on each side:

```
var regionRect = myPolyline.boundingMapRect

let wPadding = regionRect.size.width * 0.25
let hPadding = regionRect.size.height * 0.25
            
// Add padding to the region
regionRect.size.width += wPadding
regionRect.size.height += hPadding
            
// Center the region on the line
regionRect.origin.x -= wPadding / 2
regionRect.origin.y -= hPadding / 2            

myMapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(regionRect), animated: true)
```

If you don't want the padding just do this

```
var regionRect = myPolyline.boundingMapRect
            myMapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(regionRect), animated: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
func zoomToPolyLine(map : MKMapView, polyLine : MKPolyline, animated : Bool)
{
 map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(polyLine.boundingMapRect), animated: animated)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this below lines of code after calculating the directions. The below code works for me.

```
//this code is used to fit two points polyline in mapview
  let newDistance = CLLocation(latitude: pickupCoordinate.latitude, longitude: pickupCoordinate.longitude).distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: destinationCoordinate.latitude, longitude: destinationCoordinate.longitude))
  let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: pickupCoordinate, latitudinalMeters: 2 * newDistance, longitudinalMeters: 2 * newDistance)
  let adjustRegion = self.mapView.regionThatFits(region)
  self.mapView.setRegion(adjustRegion, animated:true)
```

The screen shot as below.

[image]

Hope it will help some one.